# How to install older version of google chrome for centos?

Tags: browser, archlinux, system-administration, centos6.5

I have currentlly installed Centos 6.8. i have try to install google chrome browser, but it's some error based on the way installation.

```
when i have try install "yum" way of terminal. it's showing error like:

[root@ss4u238 ~]# yum install chrome-chrome-stable
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * remi: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * remi-php55: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * remi-safe: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: centos-hcm.viettelidc.com.vn
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
**http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.**
No package chrome-chrome-stable available.
Error: Nothing to do

I had searching solution for above error, i need a comfortable architecture of my system. 

my system architecture is :

      [root@ss4u238 ~]# uname -m
              **i686**
                        OR 
      [root@ss4u238 ~]# uname -a
              **Linux ss4u238.centos.com 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 19:51:22 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux**
      [root@ss4u238 ~]# 

When i had try to install all the way installation, it's showing same error like **"architecture is not comfortable".**  

      [root@ss4u238 lib]# ./install_chrome.sh 

        **ERROR: Unsupported architecture (i686) - aborted**

      [root@ss4u238 lib]#
```

please help me friend's....  I'm waiting for your response...

Answer (score 1):

Google killing Chrome for 32-bit Linux and old versions are insecure.

You can install an alternative browser, such as Chromium.

Comment: Hi azk4n, first thank you for your answer. I'm also know google as stopped chrome for 32-bit linux. but i don't need a latest version of chrome. i want last or older version of chrome in 32 bit centos. if we can need older versions of windows (.exe), ubuntu (.dep) packege's for this link : http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php . i need older version for only centos .rpm packege or installation processes .. thank you ..

Comment: also I could not find any RPM package, only some older versions but with x64 architecture... you can install alien and try to convert the .deb package to .rpm http://www.tecmint.com/convert-from-rpm-to-deb-and-deb-to-rpm-package-using-alien/

Comment: thank you dude.. :). i will try to alien way of installation.